# How to solve dictionary based algorithms in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was practicing interview questions and came across this question could you help me solve it?

You have 2 infinite streams of data. 
Each entry in a stream contains a “key” attribute and a “value” attribute, both which are integers. 
Entry keys are increasing. 
Design an algorithm to read each entry from both streams and write it to one of 4 buckets: 
1) the key only appears in stream 1 
2) the key only appears in stream 2 
3) the key appears in both streams and the values are different 
4) the key appears in both streams and the values are the same.
**My approach**(just a vague Idea)

```
Stream1 = {}
Stream2 = {}

list1 = []#bucket1
list2 = []#bucket2
list3 = []#bucket3
list4 = []#bucket4

key1, value1 = Stream1.read()
key2, value2 = Stream2.read()

while(key1 != null or key2 != null):
  if(key1 == key2 and value1 == value2):
    list4.append(key1)
  elif(key1 == key2 and value1 != value2):
    list3.append(key1)
  elif(key1 > key2):
    list2.append(key2)
    key2 = stream2.read()
  else:
    list1.append(key1)
  key1 = stream1.read()
  key2 = stream2.read()
```

Comment: Whats the problem in this code ?

Comment: Do you want SO to assess your approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read the whole questions and correct it, however, I can still point out a few syntactical flaws.

The logical or operation in Python is 'or' not '||'. Similarly, 'and' not '&&'

Lastly, Stream1 is a dictionary which does not have `read()`. Please elaborate what you are trying to achieve.

Try this code:

```
#Pre-filled dictionaries with data in (key, value) format

Stream1 = {}
Stream2 = {}

list1 = []#bucket1
list2 = []#bucket2
list3 = []#bucket3
list4 = []#bucket4

for (key,val) in Stream1.items():
    if not key in Stream2:
        list1.append(key)
    else:
        if Stream1[key] == Stream2[key]:
            list4.append(key)
        else:
            list3.append(key)
        del Stream2[key]

for key in Stream2:
    list2.append(key)
```

Accept the answer if this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. The question is I'm given 2 infinite streams of data as mentioned in the question. I want to divide the data into 4 buckets(maybe lists or any other data structure) with the given conditions on the keys.

Comment: @maheshA Check the updated answer; it should work now. Accept the answer if it helps.